# on doesn't recognize added link element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm creating an application centered around Google Maps Javascript API and I'm using the infobox plugin.

The code for my function that creates the infobox:

```
var ibOptions = {
    disableAutoPan: false,
    zIndex: null,
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-85, -290),
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropogation: true
};


let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng),
    visible: true
});

boxText.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='user' placeholder='Add User' />"
                    + "<a href='#' class='adduser'>Add User</a>";
ibOptions.content = boxText;

let ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);

ib.open(map, marker);
```

And then in another function I'm attempting to capture the click on the button inside the infobox but nothing is happening. No errors in the console and no alert. I can log some trivial message in my adduser function so I know that everything else is working correctly and I did make sure to import jQuery.

```
export function addUser() {
    $("document").on("click", ".adduser", function () {
        alert('hello world!');
    });
};
```

I have another function that calls the jquery ui autocomplete widget and it works just fine:

```
$("#user").autocomplete({
    source: userArray
});
```

Comment: Use [delegated event handling](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @James, that's what they are doing.

Comment: @James he is. I think the problem is related to the fact that the html is inside the google maps iframe. Not entirely sure.

Comment: Use $(document) instead of $("document")

Comment: have you called the function? like `addUser()` before you click?

Comment: @VasiliyGorokhov, jQuery also recognises `"document"` as selector.

Comment: @VasiliyGorokhov I have tried that with no success also.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, the infobox works as expected. I even have another function that calls the jquery ui autocomplete widget on a text input field and that works just fine.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy, the question was not whether the infobox works as expected, but whether you have called `addUser()`. In fact, there seems little reason why you would not attach the click handler in the main script without having the need to call `addUser()` first.

Comment: I do call 'addUser' first

Comment: Please show where in your code you're calling addUser()

Comment: @mjw Sorry I recently left the office, I will post more code when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

1. $(document), not $('document') - though this is likely not causing the issue - #2 is.
2. This assumes that the button was in the DOM on page load.
   $("document").on("click", ".adduser", function () {
       alert('hello world!');
   });

Which it is not if I am reading your markup and script correctly. So, you cant bind a click event after page load using that method. You will want to use delegation instead.

```
$('#yourButtonWrapper').delegate('.adduser', 'click', function() { 
  alert('hello world!');
});
```

Comment: Wasn't delegate deprecated in favor of on?

Comment: Yes - it actually replaces several other methods - but delegate still works perfectly fine.